# How does cat interpret a file when it initially reads it?

Tags: bash, cat, gnu-coreutils

I have been researching into the usage of the cat command on a deeper level (long story) and I was wanting to clarify understanding.

When we cat a binary, let's say the cat binary itself: `cat /usr/bin/cat` we see that the terminal will slightly mess up as `cat` interprets these as escape sequences, this seems down to how `cat` interprets the bytes, but upon research, I did not find exactly how `cat` achieves this.

A further example would be a simple bash script, in which we can do `cat bash_script.sh | bash` and pipe it into bash to execute it as a bash script, this is the same for python etc.

So to summarise, I am wondering how `cat` interprets the bytes as it reads them, and then how they are printed to the screen.

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

`cat` is not interpreting the bytes. Your terminal emulator (e.g. `gnome-terminal`) is interpreting the bytes.

You can find some of the codes in the [`console_codes` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html). There may be some variation from terminal to terminal in exactly what codes they support.

You can also check out [this blog post](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html) for a description of how to use the codes to achieve various effects such as colored text.

Comment: So `cat` simply reads it to stdout and lets the terminal emulator do the rest? So the reason we can interpret them as bash scripts is purely that we pipe in bash?

Comment: Correct. If you look at the [`cat` source](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/cat.c) you will see that, other than a lot of code for handling options, all it does is move data from one pipe to another. The effect of the data depends on what is reading from the destination pipe.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, thanks for the clarification